# use json in java like in javascript

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read a json file in java to order it. I know javascript and the way to read json in javascript is so easy to do what I want to do, json is just like an array.
Is there a way to do something like that in java?

I just found gjson, json-lib, flexjson libraries and no one example about what I say, so I guess it is not possible to do it.

I need to do in java because it is for a restful server and it is all in java.

I guess I should have some classes to create all "things" inside json (in java) and put all of them in an array, after ordering them... But it makes me to have lot of classes which I don't.

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the gson user guide?

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a JSon framework in Java, such as [these examples](http://www.json.org/java/).

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend the Jackson library: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome

It won't get much simpler anyway, you have node-objects etc, it's easy to use. Here's a short guide: [Jackson in 5 minutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) Look at parsing.

Answer (score 2):

With [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```java
String json = "{ \"k1\": {\"k2\": [{\"message\": \"foo bar\"}, {\"message\": \"Hello World\"} ] } }";
JsonNode obj = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
String innerValue = obj.get("k1").get("k2").get(1).get("message").asText();
System.out.println(innerValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is impossible :). ok, first read the documentation of those libraries. Those are having the ability of serializing the objects directly. No need to re-invent the wheel again.
Only the thing you need to do is correctly manipulate them and get your work done.

I'd prefer [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), which has some performance [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library).